# ServiceStack OrmLite SUBSTRING() Incorrect for SqlServerDialect?

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

In my AppHost.cs, I'm creating an OrmLiteConnectionFactory using the SqlServerDialect.Provider:

```
OrmLiteConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Key"].ConnectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider
);
```

I'm creating a SqlExpression to get a DISTINCT list of first letters of employee last names (don't ask...).

```
SqlExpression<Employee> sql = db.From<Employee>().SelectDistinct(e => e.LastName.Substring(0,1));
```

When I run this with

```
db.Select(sql)
```

I get a SqlException "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'."  A trace shows that the query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT substring("LastName" from 1 for 1) FROM "Employee"
```

which is not the correct syntax for the SQL Server SUBSTRING function (looks like MySQL and others).

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OrmLite uses the [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) format for substring which is supported by most RDBMS's.

Support for SQL Servers `Substring()` syntax was just added [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/695114ec32b475eccf8a104220444ceb99755a90).

This change is available from v4.0.43+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Awesome support as usual - and great framework!  Thanks!